# How to updated node-gyp and/or interpret "node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log)"?

Tags: node.js, unix

I wanted play around with mongo-client by Raynos. However, when I add `"mongo-client"   : "0.2.1"` to my `package.json` dependencies, I get the following:

```
(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bson.node
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bson.node: Finished
```

The `builderror log` is empty. And if I run `npm install` again, I get a lot of `unmet dependencies`, such as:

```
npm WARN unmet dependency /node_modules/mongo-client requires reducible@'Raynos/reducible#v1.0.6' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /node_modules/reducible,
```

Now, I haven't encountered an error like this before. There are no reported issues on GIT with `mongo-client`. So, I want to know at a high-level what is going on and how to interpret the error?

Of course, I googled too. I'm thinking this might fix it:

[https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/wiki/Updating-npm's-bundled-node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/wiki/Updating-npm%27s-bundled-node-gyp)

but when I run:

```
$  sudo npm explore npm -g -- npm install node-gyp
```

I get `TypeError: Bad argument`

Any insight and guidance on next steps appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What does `builderror.log` contain? (in my case, it's located in `node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to a new place to look. The `builderror log is in the same place as yours but it's empty. I updated the question with more context from the print out when I try to install.

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors. I got the same warnings, but `mongo-client` seems to install okay (`require("mongo-client")` works), although I haven't tested it extensively.

Comment: `Unmet dependency` sounds like a problem, :D But, I didn't try to use it yet, so it sounds like it will work. I'll have time to try it out in a couple hours to see if it's working. Maybe this is because it needs to be packaged differently by Raynos?

Comment: Yes, I think so. According to its [package.json](https://github.com/Raynos/mongo-client/blob/master/package.json#L24), there's a bunch of custom dependencies that confuse `npm` (but it tries to do the right thing by installing non-custom versions). It could still fail miserably once you try it out though, but there's only one way to find out :)

Comment: I just tried running the sample code they have on npm. Too many issues even when trying stall dependencies individually. I'll use something else for now and maybe open up an issue on github. I can either close this question or if you want to officially answer it with the content in the comments, I'll happily accept it. It will be useful for someone. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get the same messages when installing `mongo-client` as well, but they are warnings and not errors, so `npm` continues.

The warnings are related to some custom dependencies (see [here](https://github.com/Raynos/mongo-client/blob/master/package.json#L19)) for `mongo-client`, which cannot be resolved by `npm`. However, it tries to do the right thing by installing non-custom versions of those dependencies instead (and tells you about it with a warning).

It might, or might not, work after installing. I got as far as running `require('mongo-client')` which didn't raise any errors, but it might still run into problems when actually in use.

Perhaps the author of `mongo-client` has a reason to include these custom dependencies, but they really should be either included as part of his own module, or he should have used a proper location (like a Github repository) from which `npm` can install them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem whilst installing gulp and its dependencies. I resolved by updating the npm package. Try: `npm install -g npm`

Answer (score 0):

Is a mongod instance running?

I received a `(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)` message trying to install the mondgodb driver while an instance of mongod was running. After stopping mongod, I no longer received the message.